# The 'resume after suspend' problem

Tags: nvidia, power-management, suspend, battery

I recently moved back to Ubuntu. And it has seriously improved. Everything is so smooth and fast. 
Except, I have this issue, like so many others, I cant wake up after suspend while on battery. 
With my charger plugged in, I can close and open the lid all day long. No Sweat. But battery powered? It's going down, Black Screen of Doom every time.

So I tried changing drivers. I removed the ones Ubuntu came with. 
And that made things worse. I heard it works for a lot of guys, bur not me. I think I did it right. I ended up in low graphics mode and couldn't get out of it. So I had to re-install, lose all my data, install Ubuntu again, and try driver thing again. Same thing. Low graphics mode. No way out. Re-install. Live with the bug.

If there are any suggestions out there, I'd love to hear 'em.

I tried to output the system error that comes after each restart, but it didn't work.

My computer is a Asus U36S sporting a NVidia 610M.

com.ubuntu.apport.apport-gtk-root says:

`/usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume`

KernelOops

Comment: Check the NVidia Control Panel for powersave settings. Try turning those off.

Comment: Yeah, i can set it to do 'Do Nothing' when i close the lid, that works, but its a pretty cheap solution i think.

Comment: I had this issue a while ago, and it turned out that it was the Ubuntu drivers that were causing it. So if you could somehow get those official nVidia drivers working, it would probably fix your issue. You said you tried to install them twice before. Did you use the "Additional Drivers" page or did you download the drivers from nVidia?

Comment: I think i did it all from terminal both times. And both times i think the official drivers where working, somehow, but i couldnt get out of Low Graphics Mode.

Comment: Try this (Backup your data first!!) : Open the Dash and type "Additional Drivers". When the list loads, pick one of the official nVidia drivers. If you're not sure which one to pick, post an image of the list here.

Comment: All backed up. Went for the 331.38 propritery driver. Crossing fingers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16446/discussion-between-pranav-marathe-and-user2800105).

Comment: Thanks for the offer Pranav. But i had to go to sleep. I'm on danish time. In the mean time I tried both 331.18 (prop trusted) and 304.117 (prop) driver versions from NVidia. And they were both worse than the Nouveau driver. Both of the drivers seemed to work a bit. The 331.18 allowed desktop to be correctly displayed, but after suspend it would freeze in some sort of screensvaer that looked like desktop without icons and topbar. The 304 booted into Low Graphics Mode and wouldnt let me leave it. Fixed with sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too but for me it is very simple. I just use the shortcut on my laptop keyboard to turn the monitor on and then again on(not sleep just the monitor). Than it all comes back to normal.

Comment: Nopes, that didnt work.

Comment: You can also try changing the brightness. It also works for me.