# without AC adapter, wake from suspend does full boot (16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

Here are the scenarios:

1. Suspend and wake with AC adapter plugged in whole time:  Works as expected
2. Suspend or wake without AC adapter (i.e. power state changes in between suspend or wake):  Full boot, session lost.
3. Suspend and wake with no AC adapter:  Full boot, session lost.
4. Suspend and wake with AC adapter, but un-plug it just for a second in between:  Full boot, session lost.

I have been searching around and I see others having "can't resume at all after suspend"  ( like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511432/the-resume-after-suspend-problem?rq=1) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884547/how-to-wakeup-ubuntu-16-04-from-suspended-state) ).  But this is slightly different, in that the machine tries to resume, but boots from scratch instead of a normal resume.

Perhaps this is expected behavior? Does suspend require power?  The thing is... this didn't used to happen.  Suspend would last for a while even without power in the past.

Might this have something to do with [hibernating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)? is that what I'm looking for? But if so... still, why did it change?  I did do an `apt update`/`apt upgrade` recently.

What information should I be gathering?  I've bee looking through `syslog` and finding some things that looked interesting, like these:

`Sep  4 13:02:00 xxxx systemd-sleep[3368]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Sep  4 13:02:00 xxxx systemd-sleep[3374]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.`

but searching for them yielded nothing but people having trouble *keeping* their systems suspended.  That is a different problem than i'm having...

Some info:

Model: Dell XPS 15

`$ uname -a
Linux xxxx 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, suspention keeps the RAM 'alive' so it requires some energy. If you have a defective battery (or no battery), what you describe is to be expected. Hibernation isn't enabled by default for a good reason.

Comment: I suppose it's possible my battery just went bad within the last 2 weeks, as this wasn't happening 3 weeks ago...